# Firebase Permissions Issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

We noticed we were unable to access data that was protected by our security rules yesterday, but the firebase status Twitter account seemed to suggest they were working on something that might have explained the issue we were having.

This morning, it seems that all issues have been resolved (everything seems good at status.firebase.com at any rate), but we're still seeing the issue.

In short, I'm getting the following browser warning when we try to load protected data:

> FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /users failed: Error:
>   permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the
>   desired data.

My security rules are really pretty minimal. We just have an Admins object in our Firebase JSON that includes user IDs like this:

```
1: true  
2: true 
...
```

The security rule itself is as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null && root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.id)",
    ".write": "auth != null && root.child('admins').hasChild(auth.id)"
  }
}
```

Again, this has always worked without any trouble, and we've made no changes to our security rules or admins object leading up to yesterday when things suddenly stopped working.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/uid/firebase-talk/s9mv4S46Qs0/YPfpNz-VBgAJ

Comment: I answered this question in full here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/dBB8oHqeDxE